# Javascript code to make Matrix wallpaper

Tags: javascript, performance

I am a javascript noob. I did this program for the sake of learning javascript in a better way. the code is to display matrix live wallpaper in the browser.
Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hacker Live Wallpaper</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wallpaper"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" async="true">
            var pageEndCounter = 0;
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = "black";
            wallpaper = document.getElementById('wallpaper');
            wallpaper.style.color = "green";
            setInterval(function() {
                pageEndCounter++;
                if (pageEndCounter >= 35) {
                    wallpaper.innerHTML = " ";
                    pageEndCounter = 0;
                }
                wallpaper.innerHTML += "</br>";
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    for (var j = returnRandomInt(2); j > 0; j--) {
                        wallpaper.innerHTML += "&nbsp";
                    }
                    wallpaper.innerHTML += returnRandomInt();
                    for (var j = returnRandomInt(2); j > 0; j--) {
                        wallpaper.innerHTML += "&nbsp";
                    }
                }
            }, 100);

            function returnRandomInt(c) {
                if (c == undefined) {
                    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                } else
                    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 / c);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It stucks to much on chrome and firefox.

Any suggestions to make the code run faster and smoother would be kindly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A) This question is off topic for this site, as it contains code that does not work. B) You have an unterminated `setInterval`, so it never ends.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix sorry to say but code works fine as intended to show random green colored numbers on a black browser window..

Comment: Yes, but it crashes... which I presume is not intended.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix Yep ot crashes because  it is taking much memory  and I posted here to find a way to optimize  it. :)

Comment: I need a second opinion on this;

Comment: If it crashes a lot, it's not working as intended. Performance is irrelevant if your approach makes the thing hang every so often. Hangs indicate the approach is *wrong*. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Mast it doesn't  crashes much often but it slow down its speed gradually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to print random 5 numbers per line spaced at random distance, Instead of using so many & nbsp; in your code you can use spans/divs with random margins/padding etc. since there will be less number of DOM elements to be parsed it should work much faster.

```
setInterval(printLine, 100);

function printLine() {
    pageEndCounter++;
    if (pageEndCounter >= 35) {
        wallpaper.innerHTML = " ";
        pageEndCounter = 0;
    }
    wallpaper.innerHTML += "</br>";
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var padding = returnRandomInt(2);
        var col = '<span style="width:20%;margin-left:' + padding+'%;">' 
                    + returnRandomInt() + '</span>'
        wallpaper.innerHTML += col;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid answering off topic questions, so as to not encourage furthe ones.

Comment: Thanks it has speed up by 5x or more now it looks much smoother.